# Symfony2 store docx file into database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docx

I'm trying to store a `.docx` file into a mysql database. I know `.docx` files are really a `.zip` file. However, I'm trying to store them into a blob field, so there should be any difference.

If I try to store a file that is not `.docx`, say `.png, .jpeg, .pdf`. everything works fine, but when I try to store a `.docx` file, I get a 500 as a response, with no error message.

This is my code:

```
public function saveResumee($slug, $file)
  {
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $resumee = new File(file_get_contents($file), $file->getMimeType(), $file->guessExtension(), $file->getClientSize());
    $em->persist($resumee);
    $em->flush(); // Everything blows up here!
    ...

    return true;
  }
```

Here is my `File` Entity

```
<?php

namespace DnD\RaHApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * File
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class File
{

  public function __construct($data, $type, $extension, $length)
  {

    $this->data = $data;
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->extension = $extension;

    if ($length) $this->length = $length;
  }

  /**
   * @var integer
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="blob")
   */
  private $data;

  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="extension", type="string", length=255)
   */
  private $extension;

  /**
   * @var integer
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="length", type="integer")
   */
  private $length;

  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=16)
   */
  private $type;


  /**
   * Get id
   *
   * @return integer
   */
  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }

  /**
   * Set data
   *
   * @param string $data
   * @return File
   */
  public function setData($data)
  {
    $this->data = $data;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Get data
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getData()
  {
    return $this->data;
  }

  /**
   * Set length
   *
   * @param integer $length
   * @return File
   */
  public function setLength($length)
  {
    $this->length = $length;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Get length
   *
   * @return integer
   */
  public function getLength()
  {
    return $this->length;
  }

  /**
   * Set type
   *
   * @param string $type
   * @return File
   */
  public function setType($type)
  {
    $this->type = $type;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Get type
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getType()
  {
    return $this->type;
  }

  /**
   * @return string
   */
  public function getExtension()
  {
    return $this->extension;
  }

  /**
   * @param string $extension
   */
  public function setExtension($extension)
  {
    $this->extension = $extension;
  }
}
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Publish your table fields definition, you could have a length field problem

Comment: @sdespont just updated my question

Comment: Did you have a look into the log file? Try in dev mode to have more details

Comment: Try to use $file->getClientOriginalExtension() instead of $file->guessExtension()

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally got it to work.

As @sdespont mentioned above, it was a length problem, the mime type of a `.docx` file its extremely large, so I just updated that field from this:

```
  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=16)
   */
  private $type;
```

To this:

```
  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
   */
  private $type;
```